# SQL with subqueries to Linq or Criteria C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, criteria

I'm trying to execute the following query in sql:

```
select r.*, 
   (select SUM(c.quantidade - c.quantidadeproduzida) 
      from pcp_trabalho c 
     where c.id_recurso = r.id_recurso
       and c.st_trabalho = 1) alocado,
   (select SUM(c.quantidade - c.quantidadeproduzida) 
      from pcp_trabalho c 
     where c.id_recurso = r.id_recurso
       and c.st_trabalho = 2) programado
from pcp_recurso r
```

st_trabalho is a enum in my project.

I tried that :

```
rv = (from r in SessionManager.GetSession().Query<RecursoCorteCircuito>()

                      select new RecursoView
                          (
                              r,
                              SessionManager.GetSession().Query<TrabalhoCorteCircuito>().Where(t => t.Recurso.Id == r.Id && t.Status == TrabalhoStatus.Alocado).Sum(t => t.Quantidade - t.QuantidadeProduzida),
                              SessionManager.GetSession().Query<TrabalhoCorteCircuito>().Where(t => t.Recurso.Id == r.Id && t.Status == TrabalhoStatus.Programado).Sum(t => t.Quantidade - t.QuantidadeProduzida)
                          )).ToList();
```

But if, for example, `SessionManager.GetSession().Query<TrabalhoCorteCircuito>().Where(t => t.Recurso.Id == r.Id && t.Status == TrabalhoStatus.Alocado)` returns `nothing`, meaning there are no "Trabalhos" with the status "Alocados", the query returns the NullException and therefore it can't execute the sum(t => t.Quantidade - t.QuantidadeProduzida).

How can I make it work ?

Comment: `Where` never returns `null`! Your `NullReferenceException` must be caused by something else.

Comment: It probably means you never stored it in the session, or aren't properly pulling it out of the session.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth It returns no result, so, it is null, and I can't make it work. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari: An empty result set and `null` are two very different things.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You are right. It returns nothing. But it still doesn't continue the query. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @LeonardoFerrari Well, one results in an exception, crashing the program, and another doesn't.  If you're getting a null exception it means you have an unrelated problem, if you're not then the question is wrong, and you need to state the real problem you're getting from the empty result set.

Comment: My where returns nothing, meaning I don't have any "trabalho" with the status "alocado", so it can't sum from an object that doesn't exist. I need to bypass that. If I execute the sql code in sql server, where the status doesn't exist, it shows "null". Did I make it more clear ? Thanks and sorry for my english !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my question. This is how I did it:

```
SessionManager.GetSession().Query<TrabalhoCorteCircuito>().Where(t => t.Recurso.Id == r.Id && t.Status == TrabalhoStatus.Alocado).Sum((int?)t => t.Quantidade - t.QuantidadeProduzida) ?? 0,
SessionManager.GetSession().Query<TrabalhoCorteCircuito>().Where(t => t.Recurso.Id == r.Id && t.Status == TrabalhoStatus.Programado).Sum((int?)t => t.Quantidade - t.QuantidadeProduzida)?? 0
```

Brief explanation:

```
Sum((int?)t => t.Quantidade - t.QuantidadeProduzida) ?? 0
```

When I put `(int?)`, the compiler let us have the null value for the sum and the `?? 0` means that, if the sum returns null, then we put the value 0.

Thank you all !